# Facebook Stetho on library project

Tags: android, facebook, aar, stetho

I've created a library to be released as an `aar`. In this library I'm using Facebook `Stetho` so in my library dependencies I'm using:

```
compile "com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.1"
```

I've also added the following lines to my library proguard file:

```
-keep class com.facebook.stetho.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.facebook.stetho.**
```

After the `aar` is generated I'm incorporating it on a app using Android Studio File -> New Module -> Import .JAR/.AAR so

```
compile project(':MyTestProject')
```

Is added to the app `build.gradle` file.

When I run the app, the app crashes with the log

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/facebook/stetho/Stetho;
....
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.stetho.Stetho" on path:.....
```

If I add the `compile "com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.1"` dependency to the app build.gradle is working as expected.

Any idea why?

Comment: Does it work if you add transitive = true on the project dependency?

Comment: Hi. Tested and did not work

Comment: I have this problem too, did you ever find a fix?